# How can I publish messages to event Hub from Azure data factory using REST API?

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-eventhub

I've used POSTMAN to publish the data using REST API into the Event hub.

How can I achieve the same in WEB activity - I get some authorization error.
Can someone please help here?

** A variant of the same scenario ** Query the data from an on prem oracle table using Copy activity and send the output to REST endpoint (Event hub) ..

Comment: *I get some authorization error*, can you be more specific?

Answer (score 1):

You can post event to an Event Hub via Web Activity in the ADF using `System Assigned Managed Identity` as the Authentication Type.

In order to make this MSI authentication work, you need to also assign at least `Azure Event Hubs Data Sender` or similar role for allowing ADF to push events to the Event Hubs.

For more detailed description, please refer the following link: https://abhinavcreed13.github.io/blog/send-event-to-event-hubs-via-adf/

Hope this helps.